# Is it 'Noonien' or 'Noonian' Soong?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

There seems to be some conflict in sources that I've noticed as to Dr Soong's name (notably [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Noonian_Soong) and [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Noonien_Soong)).  Now, this is important to me (for obvious reasons - in fact it's why the underscore is so important - fun fact).  So, my question is: **what is the canon name for Dr Soong?  Is it Noon-*ien* or Noon-*ian*?**

Comment: One difficulty is that as far as I can tell his name doesn't appear in the on-screen credits, probably because he was played by Brent Spiner.

Comment: @KeithThompson Exactly, which is probably why there was this confusion to begin with!

Comment: For what it's worth, IMDB says "Noonien Soong", Memory Alpha says "Noonian Soong, sometimes listed as Noonien Soong", and [startrek.com](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/soong) says "Noonien Soong". The latter is the only one that *might* be considered canon.

Comment: I personally prefer Noonian, just saying 

Comment: Compromise: Dr. Nooniæn Soong. ;-)

Comment: Also FWIW - Khan Noonien Singh predates Dr. Nooni(e/a)n Soong by quite a few years. So I'd say that it should be Noonien to be consistent. YMMV.

Comment: If you're uncertain, you can always fall back on "Often Wrong".

Comment: Great!   So now after this question and [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/99720/3823) someone needs to ask a question about the use of the name @Richard.   And the use of pop machines.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : A Richard question has already been [asked](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96582/why-does-richard-draw-his-own-blood-before-using-the-sword-of-truth).

Comment: @Praxis:   Well, it's a question about something a character named Richard did, not a question about the name 'Richard'

Comment: @ThePopMachine : True, true...

Comment: If the name derives from another language, there might not be a single "correct" transliteration.  See also http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: I like to think that in the future, we've moved beyond the clunky English language, and what we're experiencing is just an error in the translation of the futuristic language to our old English, like how the same last name in a language that doesn't use our alphabet gets Anglicized in several different ways.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## His name is 'officially' Noonien!

Looking at the scripts online for *TNG: Brothers*, all seem to refer to him with the 'ian' suffix rather than the 'ien' suffix.

Source 1: [Chakoteya.net](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/177.htm):

> DATA: You do bear a resemblance to Doctor **Noonian** Soong, the cyberneticist who constructed me. But, Doctor Soong was killed shortly afterward by the Crystalline Entity.

Source 2: [Antoa.com](http://antoa.com/tng/):

> CAST: ... DOCTOR **NOONIAN** SOONG

Source 3: [ST-minutiae.com](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/177.txt)

> CAST: ... DOCTOR **NOONIAN** SOONG

Source 4: [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Noonian_Soong) refers to him as **Noonian**

Yet, arguably the most canon source of all these, the page on [StarTrek.com,](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/soong) says his name is **Noonien**.

Memory Alpha makes reference to the ultimate canon sources though - the scripts and in-series references:

> Soong's first name **was spelled "Noonien" in the scripts for "Datalore"
>   and "The Measure Of A Man" while all subsequent scripts ("Brothers",
>   "A Matter of Time", "Birthright, Part I", and "Inheritance") spelled
>   the name "Noonian"**. The **okudagram** for Data's personnel file seen
>   on-screen in "Conundrum" used **"Noonian**" while the passenger manifest
>   seen in "**Inheritance**" used **"Noonien"**. The "Noonien" spelling is used
>   in several reference sources, including the Star Trek Encyclopedia and
>   StarTrek.com.

([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Noonian_Soong#Appendices))

So, considering the final line of the above quote, it seems that **Noonien is the more 'official' name used in canon, but both are within canon!**

Just to add even more confusion - because as if there isn't enough already, Memory Beta tells us that :

> The video game The Transinium Challenge gives his name as "**Nguyen Soong**".

---

As a side note, I personally prefer Noonian...

Comment: Note that chakoteya is a fan-site, not a source of official scripts. It's also notorious for spelling mistakes

Comment: @Richard - struck gold: Memory Alpha *does* refer to the official scripts at the bottom of the page: I've included the quote above.  Now we know for certain that his name is definitely Noonien or Noonian ;)

Comment: Perhaps he went by both names just to confuse people. I have a friend who spells his own name as Alistair in real life, but historically has spelt it Alastair online...

Comment: @Muzer: That's just evil!

Comment: @N_Soong - Great finds.

Comment: @Muzer: Who knows what native script Soong's name originally uses. For all we know, Noonian/Noonien might be equally valid transliterations of the same name.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Incredibly good point. Surprised nobody has mentioned this possibility (and surprised I didn't consider it!). I would feel that if there had to be extrapolated an in-universe explanation for this inconsistency, this would be the most plausible. Having said that, wouldn't most people in a culture where the Latin script is the dominant one have a "preferred" Romanisation of their name?

Comment: @Muzer: Certainly, I find it almost unbelievable even today that for many common non-Latin scripts, there are no internationally standardized Romanisations, and I'd hope the issues this implies would be solved by the 24th century.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper On the contrary, I would have hoped that Romanisations become unnecessary in the future and people don't have to butcher their own names in order to fit in (either with people or with legacy database systems)! Having said that, I can still see the value especially for handwritten purposes of being able to spell out someone else's name in a script you understand, so perhaps there will always be a future for Romanisation (not sure about typing, do we even see any examples of typing in text in Star Trek?)

Comment: (Which reminds me, the multitude of alien worlds and therefore languages as portrayed in Star Trek would really start to challenge Unicode's current 1,114,112 code point limit, so perhaps there ARE still database encoding issues in the future!)

Comment: @N_SOONG , username checks out. Did you intentionally avoid the full first name?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The problem of universal Romanisation is alive and well out of universe: http://www.businessinsider.com/qaddafi-gaddafi-kadafi-qadaffi-libya-spelling-2011-2

Comment: @Rick: Oh, I'm fully aware of this. I just find the fact shocking, incomprehensible, and annoying, and I'd hope that the issue has been resolved at latest in an enlightened future as shown on Star Trek.

Answer (score 43):

## It appears to be both.

Both spellings can be found on this 1995 action figure:

[image: A ST:TNG action figure. The outside packaging says "DR. NOONIAN SOONG, Cyberneticist and Creator of the Android Data", while the card inside the packaging is labelled "Dr. Noonien Soong".]

Comment: Wow - you really think they'd notice that error lol

Comment: @N_Soong : The left hand didn't know what the right hand was typing...

Comment: That's what I get for letting Data use both his hands so well.  +1 for the freehand circles btw ;)

Comment: No, you see, the card is in a *different continuity* from the action figure.  We just have to wait to see which one makes it into a movie or TV show first, and then we'll know which one is canon.  /s

Comment: I really want this action figure now...

Comment: @N_Soong : I'll get it for you when you hit 20K. ;-)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mark this as the correct answer, but I just think that the original script is probably more canon and reliable than a doll - no offence though!

Comment: @N_Soong : None taken...especially since not being accepted has just gotten me my second gold Populist badge!  ;-)  Seriously though, yours *is* the answer.

Comment: Maybe you should thicken up those nice freehand circles a bit? I had to hunt around on the picture for a long time to actually spot what you were referring to. (Or is that the point? ;-) )

Answer (score 18):

It's an Anglicized version of a foreign name, so there needn't be an official single answer. For example, the names Chen, Chan, Chang, Xian, Xiang, Qiang are all different attempts to render the same chinese name into english.

Personally,  I always thought it was everyone's attempt to pronounce the name Nguyen; the correct pronounciation is something like Nn-wen, but because of the spelling many pronounce it as Nuh-goo-eee-en. And Soong would seem to be an indicator of asiatic origin.